# Can I use a for loop to specify constraints in a linear problem using cvxr?

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, linear-programming, cvxr

Suppose I have a LP problem, in which:

- w is a constant column vector of dimension r
- a is a constant column vector of dimension r
- p is a constant column vector of dimension T
- d is a matrix variable of dimensions (r,T)

I have to insert the following constraint in an LP problem:

[image: constraint]

I've been using R and CVXR for a short time, so I can't figure out how to insert that double summation. Would anyone know how to help me?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to define: WCb and L are constant scalars.

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow. You could consider adding the code you already have as a reporducible example.Also, you can edit your comment back into the original post.

Comment: Yes. You can build up a list of constraints. But of course, you can also use matrix notation. Something like `tr(A^T * D)` where `A=p*v^T` and `v(j)=w(j)/a(j)`.